# Azure Pipeline Selenium tests filter not working

Tags: c#, azure, selenium, yaml

Running an Azure Pipeline and one of the tasks involves running a batch of Selenium automated tests.
I am wanting to filter which tests to run with the tag @LiveTests but when I run with this task all of the tests run and not just those that match the filter.

```
- task: VSTest@2
  displayName: 'Regression tests'
  inputs:
    testAssemblyVer2: |
        **\*Regression*.dll
        !**\*TestAdapter.dll
        !**\obj\**
    arguments: '--filter "TestCategory=LiveTests"'
```

I assume my arguments line is wrong, can anyone advise what I need to change please.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below steps to filter the `TestCategory` or `Category`

```
arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --filter TestCategory=UnitTest'
```

or

```
arguments: '--filter "Category=UnitTest"'
```

If you are using to run only UI tests on this Release, add:

```
/TestCaseFilter:"TestCategory=UITests"
```

Or

[image]

Refer here [Link 1](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Execution/Executing-Specific-Scenarios.html)  & [Link 2](https://blog.techfabric.com/3-ways-to-run-automated-tests-on-azure-devops/)

Comment: Hi, tried that, same issue